# How to display red color text on an orange background?

Tags: html, css

I have attached the screen shot.
[In image host name is not visible to red color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcFDv.png)

[image]

**Back ground color code:**

```
   .invalid {
    background-color: #CF5300;
    }
```

**upside contest displaying code**

```
  #content td.failed, .failed {
    color:#FF0000;
   }
```

Please help how to display red color as visible to user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the color? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: A snippet of the code would be nice. What exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to display red color on #CF5300;.But it's not visible to users. I need to red color and visible to users.

Comment: It's red on orange, which is a bad combination (color-blind people won't be able to read it). So you either should change the background color or the font color.

Comment: @Johannes I'm not color blind and I can barely see it.

Comment: @Rob misunderstanding: I meant that colorblind people definitely won't be able to see it; others, as you wrote will also have difficulties - it's a situation/combination to be avoided. But apart from that it's not clear what the OP really wants - the most logical thing would be to change the background to get more contrast (?)

Answer (score 1):

try a text shadow

```
   #content td.failed, .failed {
        color:#FF0000;
        text-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
        }
```

change white to a better color

Answer (score 0):

thinking about it, it seems that these red texts are links, so they won't have the normal font color, but the link color. If you want to change this color, use something like:

```
#content td.failed a:link, .failed a:link {
  color: #FCF802;
}
```

This should make those texts yellow and thereby readable on the given background.

However, if the "failed" texts/links *have to* remain red, you could assign a white background to the link itself like this to make it readable:

```
#content td.failed a:link, .failed a:link {
  color: #FF0000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#content td.failed, .failed {
    color:#FF0000;
    Background-color:white;
}
```